# Animating PNG images are not smooth and got black background in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, png, jquery-animate

I've got a problem with some elements on a site I'm working on and I can't seem to get it to work.

I've put up a little demo for the problem:
http://www.fersh.nl/pinpoint-animation/

I've got 2 problems:

In IE I can't get the image to be transparent, I tried some solutions but it isn't working, I tried this solution: http://www.viget.com/inspire/jquery-ie-png-24-ie-black-background-issue-solved/ But it still gets a black background. And I need it to be transparent cause it will be animating over an image with more than 1 color.

And the animation isn't that smooth, I'm using left and top to keep the image centered, also the quality of the image gets choppy when it's animating.

I hope someone can help me with those two problems, I'm stuck with this problem for a while now and can't find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't normally play well with PNG's. You can try using `zoom:1` on the element and see if it helps. The black background you see is a result of the IE proprietary filters.

Additionally, you should try applying the animation to the parent rather than an element. So if you have to nest your animated element within another element, you should do it. For eg, instead of using:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="/path/to/image/image1.png" />
    <img src="/path/to/image/image2.png" />
    <img src="/path/to/image/image3.png" />
    <img src="/path/to/image/image4.png" />
</div>
```

and applying the animations to the image, try using:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="/path/to/image/image1.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="/path/to/image/image2.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="/path/to/image/image3.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="/path/to/image/image4.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and apply the transitions to the `li` elements.

Also, if you're not averse to using JQuery, try using this plugin - http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/ and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help if you havent try this out. This is file save related support,

You can use the Save As command to save RGB, Indexed Color, Grayscale, and Bitmap mode images in PNG format.

Note: You can also save an image as one or more PNG files using the Save For Web & Devices command.

1. Choose File > Save As, and choose PNG from the Format menu.
2. Select an Interlace option:
3. Click OK.

None Displays the image in a browser only when download is complete.
Interlaced Displays low-resolution versions of the image in a browser as the file downloads. Interlacing makes download time seem shorter, but it also increases file size.